# configuring paypal gateway fields in spree

Tags: paypal, spree

I am trying to add the paypal gateway to spree, but am a bit confused what the different fields mean: server, login, password, signature.  are login/password supposed to be those that i use to login to paypal?  what about server and signature?

Comment: I to am confused by this, did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Found some info here:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/payment_gateways.html

server can either be "test" or "live". Not sure why they have this here (as well as a tickbox) but thats the rule anyway!

The signature you get from paypal, as an API signature. If your using developer.paypal.com its pretty easy to get one. After logging in just click "API Credentials" on the left.